# Create xhrCallbacks Ajax call + JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like use JQuery library to make my asynchronous ajax call instead of mine created that leaks if simultaneously made different calls. (Any alternative libraries than JQuery you suggest to serve this purpose?).

My current challenge is to get it working in our dev env with IE8. It works in Firefox but not IE8. The problem is that i need to use specific ActiveXObject - Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP to work in our environment. So, how do i tell JQuery to create this particular ActiveXObject instead default one? Thank You

So far(this works in Firefox):

```
var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://mkapacs.com/SimulateUser.php",
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 14000,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: {screen: "901", state: "000", trans: "cwd"},
        dataType: "xml"
        });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        var fdk="",eppKey="",uInput="";
        var xml = msg;
        try{
        fdk = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("fdk")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        eppKey = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("eppKey")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        uInput = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("user_input")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        //alert('userInput: ' + uInput + ';eppKey: ' + eppKey + ';fdk: ' + fdk);
        }catch(er){
            alert('error occured while parsing XML for fdk.Error:' + er.message);
        }


        document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML='fdk: '  + fdk + '; eppKey: ' + eppKey + '; uInput: ' + uInput;



        //alert('done: ' + msg);
        $("#log").html( msg );
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

        /*for (property in jqXHR) {
        alert(jqXHR[property].value);
    }*/
        alert( "Request failed: " + typeof(jqXHR) + textStatus );
    });
```

Comment: The default ActiveX object created by jQuery on IE8 is `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`. Are you sure that won't work?

Comment: Thank You Bfavaretto. It has been verified that Microsoft.XMLHTTP does not working in our environment

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `.ajax()` options to pass the specific XHR object you need:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    xhr: new window.ActiveXObject( "Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP" ),
    url: "http://mkapacs.com/SimulateUser.php",
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 14000,
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {screen: "901", state: "000", trans: "cwd"},
    dataType: "xml"
});
```

(Of course that would only work in IE).

Also, if you stick with jQuery, you can simplify other parts of your code. For example, this line:

```
fdk = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("fdk")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Can become simply

```
fdk = $(msg).find('fdk').text();
```

Comment: Thank You Bfavaretto. To avoid syntax error i updated it to:xhr: function (){
   window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP");
   },... But it still not working

Comment: it seems like your answer have answered my question. how would i validate at the return what type of ActiveXObject it is?

Comment: @latvian Sorry about the syntax error, bad copy/paste. I'm not sure I understand you question in the comment above. But if you're asking about how to use the correct xhr object in IE vs. other browsers, you could use something line this: `xhr: window.ActiveXObject ? new window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP") : new window.XMLHttpRequest(), //...`. Take a look at [how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/xhr.js).

Comment: Thank You. My last question was an attempt to figure out why its still not working in jQuery.ajax while it does in mine solution...jQuery must set some certain headers that prevents it working I am guessing....even if i make it working will jQuery manage the simultaneous async calls?...i don't know

Comment: The root cause of your problems could be cross-domain restrictions on ajax calls, but I'm not sure. Regarding the simultaneous ajax calls, there's not limitation imposed by jQuery, you can fire as many calls as necessary. When each one completes, your `done` callback will be called with the response.

Comment: ...so if we have two simultaneous ajax requests we are in trouble even with the jQuery library because there is only one Request object, am i correctly understand?....jQuery will not manage the calls for us

Comment: That's really easy to solve: you don't need to assing the request to a variable, just chain the callbacks like this: `$.ajax(/* ... */).done(/* ... */).fail(/* ... */)`. Wrap the whole thing in a function, and you'll have completely independent requests.